# Notification when a window you opened via JS has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I open a window via

```
mywin = window.open(...);
```

Is there a way I can be notified when `mywin` has loaded? I mean the opener be notified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `onload` event is what you are looking for:

```
mywin.onload = function(){
  alert('The window has loaded');
};
```

Comment: Ahh I didn't realize I could use that on a window like that! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   // Do something
});
```

Comment: This only tells me when the current window has loaded NOT when a separate window has loaded.